# Solve the following Diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

I need help with solving the following diophantine equation:
$$x^2+y^2=2018$$

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: $x=13,y=43$ is one solution

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $49^2>2018$ You have a typo somewhere.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think you miscalculated something  $49^2=2401$

Comment: To speed the (already simple) search, note that you can just solve the problem for $1009$ instead of $2018$ and then use the fact that $1^2+1^2=2$ to "build" a solution for $2018$.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ must both be odd and less than $45$.  Just try the possible values for $x$ and see which ones work.

Comment: I know this, it was a typo!

Comment: By the 'sum of two squares theorem' $$$$
An integer $n$ greater than $1$ can be written as a sum of two squares $a^2+b^2$ if and only if its prime decomposition contains no prime $p\equiv 3\mod 4$ raised to an odd power.$$$$

We know that $2018=1009^1·2^1$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS:**

$$2(31^2)<2018<2(32^2)$$
$$44^2<2018<45^2$$

Use these two to narrow down the range of possibilities, and test them by assigning all $y$ and seeing if $2018-y^2$ is a square number.